# A temporary coding solution that project classes can be easily upgraded to namespaces with minimal effort later

Tags: php, namespaces

The PHP community has a lot of developers creating lots of code. This means that one library’s PHP code may use the same class name as another library.
In other words, the same namespace cause trouble.

I'm planning to use namespaces in new project but namespaces support in php 5.3.0 and above.

So simply I am searching for a temporary coding solution that the project classes can be easily upgraded to namespaces with minimal effort later.

Comment: If you are running a version of PHP prior to 5.2, then you can just use long class names, which are less likely to conflict. Don't add functions that are not part of a class. So, rather than class `Widget`, you might call it `HallajiWidget` or `YourCompanyWidget`. Do bear in mind though that 5.2 is no longer supported, and 5.3 will now only get security updates - so unless you are targetting a system that uses an old platform (e.g. Wordpress), just use namespaces.

Comment: You're right. I have only doubts about servers are still on php `5.2.17`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quasi-standard is to use `_` (underscore) in your class names. This underscore can be replaced with directory separator in your autoloader just like the backslash for namespaces.

```
// directory structure
\VendorName\Namespace\ClassName.php

// class
class VendorName_Namespace_ClassName {

}
```

Look at the [PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md) standard. There you'll find an autoloader than can handle real namespaces and this kind of fake namespaces.

Comment: Using the pseudo-namespace convention of _ prefixes on class names was useful. Thanks